Category Theory built on Type Theories, Category theory as foundations
There are two questions I have, one quick and one probably long.
I am trying to investigate applications of category theory and I ran across “the category of types” in computer science.
Now, as I understand it, category theory itself needs to be built off of a theory like ZFC or more aptly BNG (for its implementation of proper classes), so as to properly define the collection of objects and morphisms.
Now the quick question is this: “Does the category of types exist in category theory, but with type theory being used as a foundation instead of set theory?”
NOTE: As far as I understand it, set theory and type theory are largely mutually exclusive foundational frameworks for mathematics. If this is wrong, please correct me.
As for the longer question, it’s really just a question of where category theory sits on the foundational hierarchy. I already found this answer: Are category-theory and set-theory on the equal foundational footing? which seems to indicate that category theory requires an underpinning theory, but the general rhetoric seems to point to category theory being capable of being foundations on its own. For instance, see: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87027/set-theory-vs-type-theory-vs-category-theory, though the discourse there seems mixed itself. Apparently John Lane Bell wrote that category theories can be viewed as type theories themselves.
I don’t even know where topos theories would lie in this whole discourse. My best guess at this point is that where category theory lies in the foundational hierarchy is either an opinionated question, or it simply depends on how one chooses to define wha is meant by “foundations.”
NOTE: If I had to choose my own definition for foundations, I’d say its a collection of axioms that, when combined, can reproduce standard mathematical results in fields like analysis, topology, measure theory, algebra, etc.
If the latter question seems a bit ill-defined so far, I think it would be this: Can category theory, without being built on top of set theory or type theory, be a foundation for mathematics itself?
Apologies if the latter question is a bit more ill-defined. Thank you to any responders.
BONUS: I can’t find an answer to this bonus question,, but if it needs to be placed elsewhere, let me know. Can type theories and set theories be compared on a logical level, or are they non-comparable? For example, does there exist a type theory that is logically equivalent to ZF?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

On the first question: certainly, yes.  (Though it does have to be a type theory that is strong enough to allow forming a type of types in the first place.  For example, Coq's system has a "hierarchy of types" Type(0), Type(1), ... in which Type(n) is of type Type(n+1) - that avoids inconsistencies which could arise if you had simply Type : Type.  Then what you get is something like "the category of level $n$ types is a level $n+1$ category" - similar to the statement in set theoretic foundations that the category of small sets is a non-small category.)

Thank you Daniel. That actually explains a lot of my confusion of how type theory was supposed to serve as a foundation while dealing with nested categorical constructions.

Some quick remarks:
(a) Category theory can provide a foundation in its own right, by making morphisms/arrows fundamental, rather than sets: cf. Lawvere's "The category of categories as a foundation for mathematics". Quoting Lambek and Scott's paper "Reflections on a categorical foundation of mathematics":

When he lectured on this at an international conference in
Jerusalem, Alfred Tarski objected: “But what is a category if not a set of objects together with a set of morphisms?” Lawvere replied by pointing out that set theory axiomatized the binary relation of membership, while category theory axiomatized the ternary relation of composition.

(b) A type theory can provide the 'internal language' / syntax of a category, which itself provides the semantics. For example, dependent type theory is the internal language of locally cartesian closed categories. The nLab has a page on the relation between type theory and category theory.
(c) A topos is a particular type of category. For example, an elementary topos can be formally defined as a category  is a category which has finite limits, is cartesian closed, and has a subobject classifier. Refer to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos#ElementaryTopos.

Okay, I have one new point of confusion then.
For point (1), if one uses set theory or type theory as a basis for catoegry theory, one needs to ensure that the theories can handle higher structures for n-categories, or ignore higher categories, mainly due to “size issues” of the theories.  How does one view category theory as a mathematical foundation without having to make some reference to the potential hierarchy of categories?
Is that resolved by having n-categories hold an analogous position as nth order logic systems?

Good question! Unfortunately that's beyond my level; i'd hoped that https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+theory+and+foundations#CFM would provide an answer, even if only in the context of ETCC, but apparently not. Leinster's "Rethinking set theory", https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6543 [PDF], a presentation of Lawvere's "Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets" (ETCS), which Lawvere developed after ETCC, notes that "[t]he approach described here is not a rival to set theory: it is set theory". Perhaps you could ask this as a distinct new question about ETCC, to make it more visible?
